# Two dynamic route handlers that handle same route?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here's the layout of our app:

```
- pages
  - book-room
    - index.tsx
    - resort.tsx
```

This means that requests to `/book-room/resort` will get handled by both `index.tsx` *and* `resort.tsx`, in that order. So...

If `index.tsx` redirects when there's a missing query param, then when that happens, the resort page will be briefly rendered while the redirect happens. That's undesirable.

The question then is how can I tell `resort.tsx` that a request has been handled already (by `index.tsx`)? Is there a way to *not* fire `resort.tsx` when a request has been handled by `index.tsx`?

Here's what our pages look like:

```
import { NextComponentType, NextPageContext } from 'next';
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { ParsedUrlQuery, Router, useRouter } from '../../../src/next/routes';

const SamplePage: NextComponentType<
  NextPageContext,
  PageProps
> = () => {
  const { query, ready } = useRouter();
  const { property } = query;

  // this redirects if property is not valid
  const propertyValid = useCheckPropertyParam(property, ready);

  return (
    <PageController
      routeReady={ready}
      routeParams={query}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: IMO, you have to use custom handler in your web server to solve your case.
For example, using expressjs can take request to `/book-room/resort`, and only render index.tsx without any additional information to resort.tsx.